# Cant connect to LDAP server using another app(Cognos) - DN not right?

Tags: apache, ldap, cognos, cognos-bi

I am using ApacheDS for a ldapserver. 
I set it up and can connect with Apache dashboard but not another 3rd party app(Cognos BI).
I have the following configuration:
uid=admin,ou=system     password: admin

```
IBM Cognos V11
Cognos Setting for clarity: (Under Security ->authentication):
Type: LDAP - General default values
Namespace ID: Test (also tried same name as the LDAP server)
Host and port: 123.456.789:10389
Base DN: ou=system (default apacheds server)
user lookup: uid=${userID} or just ${userID}
Bind user and pass: admin/admin
Other settings are all default
```

When I try to "test" the connection i get the following error in cognos:

```
['TestSameServer']
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0146 The namespace 'TestLDAPServer' is not available.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0064 The function 'Configure' failed.
[ ERROR ] The user cannot access the application at this time.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0056 Unable to authenticate.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0064 The function 'LDAPHandlePool::CreateHandle()' failed.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0026 The function call to 'ldap_simple_bind_s' failed with error code: '49'
[ ERROR ] Invalid credentials

['TestSameServer']
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0055 User input is required.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0036 Unable to authenticate because the credentials are invalid.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0125 The user 'FooB' does not exist in this namespace.
```

The user input i put in random since i couldn't even connect so it didn't matter. I tried the LDAPS port too and still can't connect.

Any help extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using LDAP as a security provider for Cognos Analytics, you would set the following within Cognos Configuration
Host and Port:
Base DN
User Lookup

My current values are 
localhost:389
ou=people,dc=cognos,dc=com
uid=${userID}  This will be the same for yours

Have a look at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/ibm-bi-capabilities/entry/using_apache_directory_server_apacheds_based_ldap_to_secure_ibm_cognos_10_2_bi_environment?lang=en for further details on the above.

Comment: I am using the following for BI Cognos Configuration under Local Configuration -> authentication ->test:

Namespace: Test
Host and port: theOtherServer'sIP:389
Base Distinguished Name: uid=admin,ou=system
Bind user name: user admin and password admin

I dont know the other parts you mentioned? Thanks

Comment: The user lookup property should be right under the Base DN.  Change it to uid=${userID}, restart the CA service and re-test.

Comment: Thanks for posting your actual setting via the edit.   Within the Apache Studio,  can you find one of your users, lets say admin, and check its DN,  I think your base DN might be off as well.

For me my Admin user has a DN of uid=admin,ou=People,dc=cognos,dc=com
So my base DN is ou=people,dc=cognos,dc=com

Comment: Hi, i edited the configuration on main topic for clarity. I dont use people or cognos or com so i am assuming i dont need those right? I know i dont use localhost since server is in another ip address. thanks

    The Admin's properties under system- uid-Admin
     uid=admin,ou=system
     ldap://11111:389/uid=admin,ou=system

Comment: OK. I installed the Apache DS on the same server as Cognos (server2). When i try the same config above i got the same connection issue. HOWEVER, if i used the same config on the server the LDAP server is on (Server1), it connects! So is there some setting or firewall or something blocking me? I can ping the ip of Server1..

Please see the above error printout

Comment: Can you test the LDAP port from server2 to server1 using power shell tcp-connect or telent

Comment: PS C:\Users\aaaaa> Test-NetConnection server1 -Port 389
WARNING: TCP connect to server1 failed

ComputerName           : server1
RemoteAddress          : server1
RemotePort             : 389
InterfaceAlias         : Local Area Connection
SourceAddress          : server2
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False

So ping is good but tcp test failed? Is the firewall blocking or something?

Comment: Port is blocked,  as a test disable the local firewall on both Server 1 and Server 2 to see what happens.

Comment: I went to firewall on both servers and added rule for both inbound and outbound. Tried All/TCP/UDP with specific and all ports and still got same error. Do i need to make an IP exception or something?

Comment: Until the powershell tcp-connect returns success you are going to be stuck,  you said ping works so its not an IP issue.  Can you tcp connect to any port on the other server?

Comment: i need to investigate that. I know we hit a sql server in server1 and i will need to dig around to see how that port was approved. 

BTW, once i do connect to the LDAP Server, how do i authenticate different users? I am bound to admin/admin so does Cognos send new uid/pass to authenticate?

Comment: Yeah that is the uid mapping,  admin is the bind user then the user lookup allows you to use the other IDs in your LDAP server.

Comment: Hi, I managed to ping the port but still cant connect with cognos BI. I even re-created LDAP server using apacheds on the same box and still can't connect. I think right now it is no longer firewall (since Apache Developer can connect to other box now) but syntax... Please see the updated Settings i have and let me know if there are any issues. Also, if you are also using Apacheds for ldap maybe any settings i shouldve done? thanks

Comment: Looks like you are past the port issue,  the new message is all about credentials, which means either your uid and passwords are wrong, or your base DN is wrong.  Within Apache studio, where are you putting your users?  ou=system, ou=users?

Comment: When i right click property on the uid=admin i just see:
DN:uid=admin,ou=system
URL: ldap://ip.225:10389/uid=admin,ou=system
I can access it via apacheds using just ou=system and admin/admin on the same server cognos is on.

Comment: Also a super crazy question - you seems like an experienced Cognos user. Do you know if Cognos works with Apache Ldap and if there's a way to find out? Maybe there's some other settings i need on cognos i am not doing..

Comment: Yes Apache LDAP works fine,  I am currently using it successfully.  I bind with the admin user as you do but my users are under ou=people, dc=cognos, dc=com

Comment: can you provide an example of your structure? 
How do you connect your cognos to LDAP? Do you just bind admin and provide dn and hostname and port? Did you set any other options?

And how are the ldap users created? i think there are ways to create uid or cn or something. If you can provide details for a single user you made maybe i can replicate and see if it works? thanks

Comment: Did you get this sorted with the link provided?  I have updated the solution with it as well.

Comment: I followed it (without creating the users under dc because had problems adding to it) and just tried the default UID of Admin. Still didn't work:
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0146 The namespace 'LDAP_FOO' is not available.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0064 The function 'Configure' failed.
[ ERROR ] The user cannot access the application at this time.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0056 Unable to authenticate.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0064 The function 'LDAPHandlePool::CreateHandle()' failed.
[ ERROR ] CAM-AAA-0026 The function call to 'ldap_simple_bind_s' failed with error code: '49'

Comment: I also got the following when  i entered uid/pass during the test":
[ ERROR ] Invalid credentials
['BSLDAP']
[ ERROR ] AAA-AUT-0013 The user is already authenticated in all available namespaces.

Comment: BTW, why are you using 389? do i need to set that instead of 10389?

Comment: The port is whatever you have set within the directory server.  This is also covered in the step by step document.  Creating the users under dc is probably the key.

Comment: I am able to use the DEFAULT ou=system to login as admin/admin. But the other DN i mentioned cognos etc. didn't work. I think for now ou=system might be best place?
Also, on cognos config the weblink i cant seem to see "admin" when i try to add members to cognos group. Is there some permission i need to see those users?